# Meteor meta:susy package surprising path

Tags: meteor, sass, susy

I'm trying to use the meta:susy package on my meteor installation. On my iMac there are no problems, but on windows 10 it say:

```
throw Error("surprising path" + p);
Error: surprising path: /{meta:susy}/susy
```

I removed the fourseven:scss package, then I added it and the susy:meta package again, but the problem persists.

How can I solve it? I need to use it in my laptop too..

Thank you all!

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Anyone knows the possible solution? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a [known issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6619) in 1.3, so use 1.3.1:

```
meteor update --release=1.3.1
```